# Why does declaring a descriptor class in the __init__ function break the descriptor functionality?

Tags: python, descriptor

In class B below I wanted the `__set__` function in class A to be called whenever you assign a value to `B().a` . Instead, setting a value to `B().a` overwrites `B().a` with the value. Class C assigning to `C().a` works correctly, but I wanted to have a separate instance of A for each user class, i.e. I don't want changing 'a' in one instance of C() to change 'a' in all other instances. I wrote a couple of tests to help illustrate the problem. Can you help me define a class that will pass both test1 and test2?

```
class A(object):
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print "__set__ called: ", value

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

class C(object):
    a = A()

def test1( class_in ):
    o = class_in()
    o.a = "test"
    if isinstance(o.a, A):
        print "pass"
    else:
        print "fail"

def test2( class_in ):
    o1, o2 = class_in(), class_in()
    if o1.a is o2.a:
        print "fail"
    else:
        print "pass"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accordingly to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors):

> *The following methods **only apply** when an instance of the class containing
>   the method (a so-called descriptor
>   class) **appears in the class dictionary
>   of another new-style class**, known as
>   the owner class. In the examples
>   below, “the attribute” refers to the
>   attribute whose name is the key of the
>   property in the owner class’ `__dict__`.
>   Descriptors can only be implemented as
>   new-style classes themselves.*

So you can't have descriptors on instances.

However, since the descriptor gets a ref to the instance being used to access it, just use that as a key to storing state and you can have different behavior depending on the instance.

Comment: On second thought, maybe I can't live with that. In my application I want to put member functions in A that also depend on the state of the owner class. So for example: 
Owner(state info)
Owner.a = data
Owner.a.foo()

How does foo get the state info from Owner?

Comment: @unknown (google): oh, for that you store the data on the instance itself. So you can fetch it from the methods.

Comment: I don't quite follow you, can you elaborate on that just a bit?

Comment: @unknown (google): def __set__(self, instance, value): instance._value = value

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class that can pass the original tests, but don't try using it in most situations. it fails the isinstance test on itself!

```
class E(object):
    def __new__(cls, state):
        class E(object):
            a = A(state)
            def __init__(self, state):
                self.state = state
        return E(state)

#>>> isinstance(E(1), E)
#False
```

Comment: that's a class factory function, disguised as a class

Answer (score 0):

I was bitten by a similar issue in that I wanted to class objects with attributes governed by a descriptor. When I did this, I noticed that the attributes were being overwritten in all of the objects such that they weren't individual.

I raised a SO question and the resultant answer is here: [class attribute changing value for no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259468/class-attribute-changing-value-for-no-reason/22262821#22262821)

A good document link discussing descriptors is here: http://martyalchin.com/2007/nov/24/python-descriptors-part-2-of-2/

An example descriptor from the aforementioned link is below:

```
class Numberise(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if self.name not in instance.__dict__:
            raise (AttributeError, self.name)
        return '%o'%(instance.__dict__[self.name])

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print ('setting value to: %d'%value)
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
```